# How to figure out whether the operation is CPU intensive or not

Tags: c#, asynchronous, task, measure

I have some code to review:

```
Task.WhenAll(contracts.Select(x => Task.Run(() =>
{
    // here some 30 lines of synchronous code

}))).GetAwaiter().GetResult();
```

My thought that this code is better to run synchronously in a plain `foreach` as 30 lines of codes seem to me not too much CPU intensive operation. But I'm not very sure for that.

If an operation takes more that 50 ms to complete, it's better to run it asynchronously. Therefore, I have to measure the performance of it. But it is impossible to do while reviewing the pull request.

So, is the any other way to figure out whether the operation is really CPU intensive?

**UPDATE**:

**If an operation takes more that 50 ms to complete, it's better to run it asynchronously.**

I read it from Stephen Cleary's blog:
https://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/04/ui-guidelines-for-async.html

Comment: "If an operation takes more that 50 ms to complete, it's better to run it asynchronously" That´s a really bad generalization. In fact asyncronity does not imply any multi-threading and thus if or if not multiple cores are used.

Comment: "If an operation takes more that 50 ms to complete, it's better to run it asynchronously" says who?

Comment: If `contracts` could be a potentially large collection and you want to profit from parallelism, this is a job more suited to a `Parallel.ForEach` or PLINQ's `.AsParallel()`. Otherwise, there seems to be nothing to be gained from parallelism at all, let alone asynchrony.

Comment: What exactly is your question? It seems by CPU-intensive you mean everything slower then 50ms. Based on this assumption you may just measure if your code is CPU-intensive or not. So are you asking how to measure?

Comment: Do you have Real-Time-Requirements?

Comment: No, 50 *microseconds* is a minimum.  50 msec might be appropriate if code affects UI responsiveness, there is no real cue that this is the case.  But above all, you'll have to have insight in how much data the Select() statement spits out, distributing hundreds of processing tasks across 4+ threadpool threads is not a bug, as long as they take the bare minimum.

Comment: @HimBromBeere, no, in contract, I consider CPU intensive all that over 50 ms. This is not my code. I'm revieving it. My question how can I guess whether it take longer than 50 ms just reviewing the PR.

Comment: Just use a `StopWatch` and take the `EllapsedMilliSeconds`.

Comment: Stephen Cleary cites Jason Olson ([keeping-apps-fast-and-fluid-with-asynchrony-in-the-windows-runtime](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsappdev/2012/03/20/keeping-apps-fast-and-fluid-with-asynchrony-in-the-windows-runtime/)) and refers specifically to UI responsiveness, not just any operation.

Comment: _"how can I guess whether it take longer than 50 ms just reviewing the PR"_ you cannot. I mean - you can _guess_ , but you'd be probably wrong most of the times.

Comment: Even if there was good reason to assume the operation took sufficiently long to make it worthwhile to do asynchronously for the sake of responsiveness, the current code still makes no sense, as it just introduces a synchronous wait around the whole thing being done asynchronously. This would not keep a UI responsive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no point in running CPU operations asynchronously at all, you just add a lot of overhead and use same CPU resource after that as well.

The point with asynchronous operations is that if you have to wait, then you don't need to block the tread, so it can do something else.

So even if the operation runs for 2 minutes of pure CPU, you don't win anything by calling it asynchronously.

Moreover you are just synchronously waiting for all the operations to complete anyway. So you can use your `Task.Run` to run operations in parallel, but you don't need to do anything else about that.

As far as I know the only difference between just doing `.Result` and `.GetAwaiter().GetResult()` will be the type of exception you are getting.

So my point is: there is nothing async in your code already, so there is nothing to measure.

Comment: That´s not whrong of course, however it does not answer the question of OP.

Comment: @IlyaChernomordik, but I if we run long running operation like you said 2 minutes from UI thread, we will freeze it for 2 min, isn't?

Comment: @DmitryStepanov You are right, but waiting for code to finish "blocking" the UI Thread won't improve that.

Comment: @DmitryStepanov If you don't want to block UI thread then just await Task.WhenAll(...)

Comment: Yes, if you have a UI thread that you don't want to block, then you you need to run your operations as async/await all the way down and they as the other say do await.Task.WhenAll. So I guess my point was not completely correct, there is no need to run your CPU intensive operations async still, but running await on Task.WhenAll will help you not block the UI tread.